# Dealing with Prompts while using Perl and SSH

Tags: perl, ssh

While using perl and Net::SSH:Expect, does anyone know how to continue to press "\r\n" until you receive a certain type of prompt "#"?  The router doesn't accept any type of command to extend the terminal length such as "terminal length 0".  Output commands ">" are not support on the router either.  I've tried using the below command, but still no luck

```
    $ssh->send("show vlan all\r\n");
    START:
    $ssh->send("\r\n");
    while ( $ssh->has_line() ) {

        print $output= $ssh->read_line() ."\n";
        print OUTPUT "$output\n";

        }   
    $ssh->waitfor('#',5) or  goto START;
```

I need some form of loop that sends a carriage return until a prompt is received.

Comment: Is there some prompt printed when a screen is filled and waiting on a carriage return (i.e., "-- More --")?

Comment: Yes, the prompt says to press any key.  I actually solved the problem by performing a nested loop.  I continue to send CR to the command line until i receive a "#" symbol.  When I receive a "#" symbol, i break out of the parent loop

Answer (score 0):

I actually solved the problem by performing two loops.  WIthin the inner loop, I continue to send CR to the command line until i receive a "#" symbol.  When I receive a "#" symbol, i break out of the parent loop.

```
while($Defined)
{
while(#ssh->has_line(){
//do stuff
}
$ssh->exec("D\r\n");
if ( index( $output, "#" ) != -1 ) 
{$Defined = undef;
}else {}
}
```